# TestStack.Seleno/Selenium, C#: Does finding elements have minimum, non overrideable timeouts?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, seleno

I am using TestStack's Selenium wrapper [Seleno](https://github.com/TestStack/TestStack.Seleno) for UI testing. I seem to have stumbled upon some weird behavior that I am unable to determine the source of.

Say that I try to find an element that may or may not exist in the DOM:

```
public void FindStuffByCss(string selector)
{
    Find.OptionalElement(By.CssSelector(selector), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
}
```

I would expect this function to time out after 200 milliseconds if it doesn't find any elements in the DOM, but it actually takes 10 seconds! At first, I thought this was because of the cssSelector I used, but it doesn't seem like that's the case.. Because the following times out after 500 milliseconds:

```
public void FindStuffByJquery(string selector)
{
    Find.OptionalElement(By.jQuery(selector), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
}
```

Unless JQuery is 20 times faster than whatever Selenium/Seleno uses to perform its By.CssSelector query, this is a little odd. To me it looks like there is a default minimum timeout that you cannot override.

Has anyone noticed similar behaviour? I would really like to know why, and if there is a way to override it.

Comment: Do you have an `implicitWait()` defined?

Comment: Yes, Seleno use a `implicitwait` of 10 seconds by default. It makes sense that it is this timeout that cause the 10 second delay with the `By.CssSelector` method. But that does not explain how the `By.jQuery` only takes 500 milliseconds. Regardless, shouldn't the timeout passed as an argument override the `implicitWait` ?